# Exception on application exit when using DispEventAdvise

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have the following test setup, written in Visual Studio 2015, and using Windows SDK 7.1:

- C# project (TestCs) with COM attributes. It exposes a 'Run' method, and invokes 'NotifyEvent' event
- C++ DirectShow filter (TestFilter). It is built on TransInPlace sample, and hosts TestCs
- C++ Console Application (TestApp). It simply load the TestFilter

When compiling in Debug, and running the test application, the functionality seems to work, and event is handled as expected.
The problem is, that the application crashes on exit, and so far I failed figuring out why. Will very much appreciate anybody's help here.

And now for the details:
Application looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <streams.h>

// {E705C8D3-EE60-4012-9E83-3CFE4A11D1B5}
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_TestFilter,
    0xe705c8d3, 0xee60, 0x4012, 0x9e, 0x83, 0x3c, 0xfe, 0x4a, 0x11, 0xd1, 0xb5);

void Test()
{
    CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pFilter;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TestFilter, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&pFilter);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return;
}

void main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    Test();
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

The crash happens when exiting the scope of main function, and I can't get anything from the call stack.

The CS test has the following interface defined

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestCs
{
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IFireTestCsEvents
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        void NotifyEvent(string message);
    }

    public delegate void NotifyEventEventHandler(string message);

    public interface ITestCs : IDisposable
    {
        event NotifyEventEventHandler NotifyEvent;

        bool Run(string fileName);

        void Close();
    }
}
```

This is the interface's implementation

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestCs
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IFireTestCsEvents))]
    public class TestCsImp : ITestCs
    {
        public event NotifyEventEventHandler NotifyEvent;

        public TestCsImp()
        {
        }

        public bool Run(string fileName)
        {
            NotifyEvent?.Invoke(fileName);
            return true;
        }

        public void Close()
        {
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

As for the TestFilter, it is based on TransInPlace class, and adding TestCsWrapper object to host TestCs
This is the header file

```
#pragma once

#import "TestCs.tlb"
using namespace TestCs;

class TestCsWrapper :
    public IDispEventSimpleImpl<1, TestCsWrapper, &__uuidof(IFireTestCsEvents)>
{
public:
    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(TestCsWrapper)
        SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1, __uuidof(IFireTestCsEvents), 0x1, HandleEvent, &NotifyEvent)
    END_SINK_MAP()

    void __stdcall HandleEvent(BSTR message);
public:
    TestCsWrapper();
    virtual ~TestCsWrapper();

    bool Open();
    void Close();

    bool IsValid();

    bool Load(const wchar_t *fileName);
private:
    ITestCsPtr m_pTestCs;

    static _ATL_FUNC_INFO NotifyEvent;
};
```

And this is the implementation

```
#include "Pch.h"
#include "TestCsWrapper.h"

_ATL_FUNC_INFO TestCsWrapper::NotifyEvent = { CC_STDCALL, VT_EMPTY, 1, { VT_BSTR } };

#define CREATE_CRASH

void __stdcall TestCsWrapper::HandleEvent(BSTR message)
{
    ::SysFreeString(message);
}

TestCsWrapper::TestCsWrapper()
{
}

TestCsWrapper::~TestCsWrapper()
{
    Close();
}

bool TestCsWrapper::Open()
{
    m_pTestCs = ITestCsPtr(__uuidof(TestCsImp));
    if(!IsValid())
        return false;

#ifdef CREATE_CRASH
    DispEventAdvise(m_pTestCs);
#endif
    return true;
}

void TestCsWrapper::Close()
{
    if(IsValid())
    {
#ifdef CREATE_CRASH
        DispEventUnadvise(m_pTestCs);
#endif
        m_pTestCs->Close();
        m_pTestCs->Release();
        m_pTestCs.Detach();
    }
}

bool TestCsWrapper::IsValid()
{
    return (m_pTestCs != NULL);
}


bool TestCsWrapper::Load(const wchar_t *fileName)
{
    if(!IsValid())
        return false;

    BSTR bstr = ::SysAllocString(fileName);
    VARIANT_BOOL success = m_pTestCs->Run(bstr);
    ::SysFreeString(bstr);
    return success == VARIANT_TRUE;
}
```

When I disabled DispEventAdvise code, the application exits without any exception.

In the filter's CreateInstance call I added the following code

```
bool TestFilter::Open()
{
    if (!m_testCs.Open())
        return false;

    m_testCs.Load(L"some messsage");
    return true;
}
```

A complete Visual Studio solution code is available for demonstrating this, and can be provided if needed

Hope to find out what I'm doing wrong. 
Thanks

Comment: You do have to assume that nobody will enjoy copy/pasting this code.  There's some "clearly wrong" code.  The return type of HandleEvent must be HRESULT, return S_OK so the C# code won't throw an exception.  SysFreeString() is not correct, that's the caller's job, it will make the CLR fail with an AccessViolationException.  Interface inheritance in C# doesn't work like it does in COM, if you "inherit" from IDisposable then you must make Dispose() the first member of the interface explicitly.  The Release() call is not correct, the smart pointer type already does that.

Comment: Do make sure you can see diagnostics from the debug heap, look in the Output window.  The program exit code is somewhat likely to be 0xC0000374 due to the heap corruption.

Comment: Thank you Hans. After  applying the fixes as you noted, the problem persists.

Comment: As for the error line in output window it looks like this: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF6539DA26 (clr.dll) in TestApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Comment: In any case, a full VS solution can be downloaded from [link](https://spaces.hightail.com/receive/f9Gfh1r0Mi)